# Keep boxplots written in R code not responding to filters in PowerBi although jitter does

Tags: r, ggplot2, powerbi, boxplot

This code is written in R for a visual in PowerBi

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=as.factor(dataset$months), 
                    y=dataset$urine_test, color=as.factor(subject))) +
     geom_boxplot(color="black",outlier.shape = NA)+
     geom_jitter(size=1)+
     theme_bw()
```

It responds to a filter just showing urine analytes data from one or several filtered subjects over time, but then the boxplot adapt to those subjects while I want them to represent the whole population regardless of the filter within the same plot

Keep boxplots not responding to filters

Comment: could you please share your data using `dput(dataset)`? so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you want a boxplot for the population, I recommend using an `index` variable.

Sample code:

```
library(ggpplot2)
library(ggthemes)


dataset$months=factor(dataset$months, levels=c("January", "February", "March","April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
                                                   "September","October","November","December"))
    
    ggplot(dataset, aes(x=factor(dataset$months), 
                        y=dataset$urine_test, color=index)) +
      geom_boxplot(color="black",outlier.shape = NA, aes(fill=index))+
      labs(x="", y="Urine_test")+
      geom_jitter(size=1)+
      theme_bw()+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle =45 , hjust = 1,family="Times", face="bold", size=12, color="black"), 
            axis.title.x = element_text( face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
            axis.text.y = element_text( face="bold", size=12, color="black"),
            axis.title.y = element_text( face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
            strip.text = element_text(size=10, face="bold"),
            legend.position = "none")
```

Plot:

[image]

Sample code:

```
dataset<-structure(list(months = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("January", 
"February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", 
"September", "October", "November", "December"), class = "factor"), 
    urine_test = c(2, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0.5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 0, 1, 0.5, 
    0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5), subject = c("A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), index = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In PowerBi you can filter by subjects, then the visual boxplot() + jitter() only displays the data related to those subjects filtered. However, is there any way to make thevisual displaying jitter() for only those subjects filtered but still displaying the boxplots from the whole subjects set?